# How to view EXIF when value is (0/0) in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, exif

I am using Python to view EXIF in images. For the exposure bias value, the value in my image is (0/0) which throws a ZeroDivisionError when accessed.

I would like to prevent this error from being thrown and view the value without hard coding "(0/0)" if the error is thrown. I am hesitant doing it this way because there may be another ZeroDivisionError for a value where "(0/0)" is not the specific value. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Below is my current code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
from exif import Image

with open(os.path.expanduser("~") + "/Desktop/IMG_20210316_125543.jpg", "rb") as test_file:
    test_image = Image(test_file)

image_members = []

image_members.append(dir(test_image))

for index, image_member_list in enumerate(image_members):
    print(f"Image {index} contains {len(image_member_list)} members:")
    for index, value in enumerate(image_member_list):
        try:
            print(value + ":", test_image.get(value, "unknown"),"\n")
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print(value + ":", "you tried to divide by zero","\n")
        
# both of the following print statements throw ZeroDivisionError
print(test_image.exposure_bias_value)
print(test_image.get("exposure_bias_value", "unknown"))
```

Thank you

Comment: I think EXIF values are defined as rational numbers which seems like a good fit for Python *"fractions"*... https://pymotw.com/3/fractions/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Exif manual](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/download_e.html?DC-008-Translation-2019-E): rationales like `0/0` can have a different meaning per key. Examples:

- `A432` (LensSpecification): the minimum F number is unknown.
- `A462` (SourceExposureTimesOfCompositeImage): the specific value (i.e. total exposure period, max exposure of all, min exposure time...) is invalid, meaning it is not available.

That's why you should treat them uncomputed and need to interpret them.